# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr? Table Multicolumn

Tags: tables

I get that error, can you help me?

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | }
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Method Function}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Lineal} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Pol} &     \multicolumn{5}{c}{Gaussian} & \multirow{2}{*}{S method} & \multirow{2}{*}{Line} & \multirow{2}{*}{Upload} & \multirow{2}{*}{Fourier} & \multirow{2}{*}{Marconi} & \multirow{2}{*}{Tesla} \\
& grade 1 & grade 2 & grade 3 & grade 4 & $\sigma=0.15$ & $\sigma=0.25$ & $\sigma=0.5$ & $\sigma=2$ & $\sigma=3$ \\
\hline
Template & 57\% & 80\% & 92 & 89 & 89 & 94 & 97 & 97 & 94 & 92 & a & b & c & d & e f \\
\hline
Template & 57\% & 80\% & 92 & 89 & 89 & 94 & 97 & 97 & 94 & 92 & a & b & c & d & e f \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Your first row specifies 17 columns, but you have only 10.

Comment: That's all you have in your tex-file? where is preamble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You need the following text of tex-file.[image]

```
%document information
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}

% packages
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}                        
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | }
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Method Function}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Lineal} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Pol} &     \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Gaussian} & \multirow{2}{*}{S method} & \multirow{2}{*}{Line} & \multirow{2}{*}{Upload} & \multirow{2}{*}{Fourier} & \multirow{2}{*}{Marconi} & \multirow{2}{*}{Tesla} \\
\cline{3-11}
& & grade 1 & grade 2 & grade 3 & grade 4 & $\sigma=0.15$ & $\sigma=0.25$ & $\sigma=0.5$ & $\sigma=2$ & $\sigma=3$ & & & & & &\\
\hline
Template & 57\% & 80\% & 92 & 89 & 89 & 94 & 97 & 97 & 94 & 92 & a & b & c & d & e & f \\
\hline
Template & 57\% & 80\% & 92 & 89 & 89 & 94 & 97 & 97 & 94 & 92 & a & b & c & d & e & f \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```